# How does the kubernetes scheduler know what HostPorts are used on what Hosts?

Tags: resources, kubernetes, scheduler

I need to dig deeper into a scheduling issue with kubernetes 1.7:

- I have 18 nodes (of 119) with the label `app-nodes=true`

  ```
  kubectl get nodes -l app-nodes=true
  NAME             STATUS     AGE       VERSION
  app-001   Ready      53d       v1.7.0+coreos.0
  app-002   Ready      53d       v1.7.0+coreos.0
  app-003   Ready      53d       v1.7.0+coreos.0
  app-004   Ready      53d       v1.7.0+coreos.0
  app-005   Ready      53d       v1.7.0+coreos.0
  app-006   Ready      53d       v1.7.0+coreos.0
  app-007   Ready      53d       v1.7.0+coreos.0
  app-008   Ready      53d       v1.7.0+coreos.0
  app-009   Ready      53d       v1.7.0+coreos.0
  app-010   Ready      53d       v1.7.0+coreos.0
  app-011   Ready      53d       v1.7.0+coreos.0
  app-012   Ready      53d       v1.7.0+coreos.0
  app-013   Ready      53d       v1.7.0+coreos.0
  app-014   Ready      53d       v1.7.0+coreos.0
  app-015   Ready      53d       v1.7.0+coreos.0
  app-016   Ready      53d       v1.7.0+coreos.0
  app-017   Ready      53d       v1.7.0+coreos.0
  app-018   Ready      53d       v1.7.0+coreos.0
  ```
- I have a deployment w/18 replicas with NodeSelector `app-nodes=true` and `HostPort: 4567`

My deployment is stuck with 17/18 pods deployed. With the last one pending with the error:

> No nodes are available that match all of the following predicates::
>   MatchNodeSelector (98), PodFitsHostPorts (18)

- All nodes - except node 11 - have iptable chain Docker with 4567 configured
- There are no dead/stuck pods hanging around in kubectl (taking up the port)
- The nodes are all `Ready`
- I have inspected deployment / pod / rs
- Have looked at events
- Deleted pods
- Scaled down and up.

With no additional information. I even tried going trough etcd to see if I could find stale data.

How does the kubernetes scheduler determine the Allocated HostPorts?
How can I look inside the scheduler?

Comment: Are you sure that node 11 has the `app-nodes=true` label, and nothing is running on it on port 4567 (outside of Kubernetes)?

Comment: Adde the results for the labels and I am getting he info on the host ports. Though form experience - if something outside kubernetes that takes a port, the error is different (I think it silently gets stuck in pending with no errors) -
 but I Will this validate on another system.)